# Como pesquisar em uma tabela por data e somar valores contidos nela?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

É o seguinte pessoal, estou com muita dificuldade em criar um pesquisa por data no meu banco sqlite do android.
Queria pesquisar as tabelas por data, se possivel, queria fazer uma condicional que que detectasse a data atual, e somente atualizasse a tabela (somando certos valores) não precisando criar novas tabelas.

Desde de já agradeço grandemente a quem me der uma "luz" sobre essa pergunta.

Minha tabela é essa:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTRADA (

    _id                INTEGER       NOT NULL
                                     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    DATA                DATE         NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    SALDO               VARCHAR (20),
    DEPOSITO            VARCHAR (20),
    ECONOMIAS           VARCHAR (20),
    SALARIODOMES        VARCHAR (20),
```

Comment: Como assim? Você quer checar se o campo `data` é igual a data atual?

Comment: Isso, quero checar se o campo data é a data atual (por isso o CURRENT_DATE, alias, essa tabela que criei ira sempre ser criada com a data atual mesmo? Me desculpa a outra pergunta, mas comecei a mexer com sql a muito pouco tempo XD).

Comment: Dai, queria criar uma função que checasse pela data (pode ser a data atual ou outra), e somasse os campos de SALDO.. alias, queria criar somente uma tabela dessa por data(dia)... dai o somatorio seria referente ao dia da data da tabela (isso sera feito sempre atualizando a mesma tabela né? Como faço isso tb? kkkk, desculpa minha falta de experiencia no assunto)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, acredito que esteja querendo algo deste tipo:

SQL SERVER

```
    UPDATE TABELA_A SET VALOR = X+Y
        WHERE DATA = GETDATE()
```

ou Oracle

```
    UPDATE TABELA_A SET VALOR = X+Y
        WHERE DATA = SYSDATE()
```

A condição que você faz para verificar é na própria clausula WHERE ou AND do UPDATE. Dê uma olhada no seguinte link que talvez possa te ajudar.

http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2975/comandos-basicos-em-sql-insert-update-delete-e-select.aspx

Comment: Seria algo assim sim Eric. Como faço para pegar o valor que estava anteriormente no campo SALDO, e soma-lo ao novo valor que estarei atualizando na tabela?

Comment: "Selecionar todas as tabelas com a data atual, e somar os seus campos VALOR".. Também tem como executar essa instrução? Se sim, como ficaria em SQL?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, o link me ajudou mais sobre os comandos em SQL :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a Classe Calendar para obter e registrar o dia, mes e ano. Converta para String e grave como String no banco de dados. Use double para o valor(ponto não virgula).
"Create table..._id INTEGER...d(para o dia) text + m(mes)..y(ano) tudo "TEXT", o valor deixe em "double" na criação da tabela

//Na Classe em que fará a pesquisa use

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;
```

//depois...

```
public void somando() {
   Cursor cursor;
cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM nomeDaSuaTabela WHERE d = ? AND m = ? AND y = ?",new String[] { dia, mes, ano });
//obtenha do sistema os valores da data ou de um EditText 
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    double total = cursor.getDouble(0);// o argumento é o int
                                                        // indice da coluna

                    mensagemExibir(
                            "Total",
                            "A Soma do Valor doQueVcQuer do dia "
                                    + dia
                                    + " de "
                                    + mes
                                    + " de "
                                    + ano
                                    + " é de\n R$ "
                                    + String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",
                                            total)));

                }
public void mensagemExibir(String titulo, String texto) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                SuaClasseContexto.this);
        mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
        mensagem.setMessage(texto);
        mensagem.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        mensagem.show();
        mensagem.setCancelable(true);

    }
```

jogue o método somando() dentro do evento de um Button.
Na mensagem vc tbm pode usar um NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().
Embora se vc for editar depois qualquer erro na digitação do valor o android costuma arredondar os doubles depois do ponto. Aí tem que rebolar mais se quiser muita precisão. Abs

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, me esclareceu de como usar o SUM (estava usando um while para fazer a soma :P).